# Draw a plot of a trajectory without using matplotlib

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw the lines of a trajectory and I want to do it creating a white image and painting the trajectory on top. I want to avoid using `matplotlib`, because later I have to do some other operations with the result.

My problem is that the XY values are float and this error appears:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

How can I "normalize" these values to an integer without losing information?

This is an example of one coordinate, `[0.714169939757303, 0.285830060242697]`.

My code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = ...
img = np.ones((100, 200, 3))
for r in range(df.shape[0]):
    matrix_XYZ = np.array(df.loc[r][1:])
    denom = np.sum(matrix_XYZ)
    X = df.loc[r][1]
    Y = df.loc[r][2]
    x = X / denom
    y = Y / denom
    coor = [x, y]
    img[coor[1], coor[0], :] = (255, 0, 0)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to provide some more information about the range of X and Y, and where you want them in the image. Creating a simple dataframe with some typical values could help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to round your points to the nearest pixel to actually draw them. You can't avoid losing information; a plot can only ever be as accurate as its resolution in pixels. (You could try drawing a point "between" pixels, by setting the two pixels it is between to 50% instead of one pixel to 100%, or you could try to do "subpixel smoothing" as is done when rendering fonts on LCDs, but those tricks probably aren't worth the effort.)

You also probably want your coordinates to be in pixels, rather than between 0 and 1, as they are after you divide them by the sum of matrix_XYZ.

Also, ones is going to give you an image with 1/255 brightness in each color, if I'm right that your image is supposed to be R, G, B on a scale of 0-255.

Try something like this:

```
# Set image dimensions. We scale all the numbers to use the 
# full axis range, so your data will be stretched if this isn't square.
width = 100
height = 200
# Start with all white: (255, 255, 255) everywhere
# Note that imshow expects (col, row, channel) indexing
img = np.ones((height, width, 3)) * 255
for r in range(df.shape[0]):
    matrix_XYZ = np.array(df.loc[r][1:])
    # We're going to divide the numbers by the total of X, Y, and Z.
    # This isn't the same as normalizing to length 1 
    # (which would be dividing by the square root of the sum of the squares).
    # It's also not the same as subtracting the minimum
    # and dividing by the maximum minus the minimum in each dimension, 
    # like you would do for a normal auto-fit to axes.
    # Are you sure this is what you want?
    denom = np.sum(matrix_XYZ)
    X = df.loc[r][1]
    Y = df.loc[r][2]
    x = X / denom
    y = Y / denom
    # Now you have X and Y both on range 0-1
    # Convert to pixels
    coor = [int(round(x * width)), int(round(y * height))]
    # Set the pixel to red only.
    # I'm not sure about fancy slice assignment, so do each channel separately.
    # Also note that imshow expects (col, row, channel) indexing, so Y first.    
    img[coor[1], coor[0], 0] = 255
    img[coor[1], coor[0], 1] = 0
    img[coor[1], coor[0], 2] = 0

# imshow is still Matplotlib, so this isn't really "not using Matplotlib".
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```